# regular expression for comma separated years

Tags: c#, regex

I need a hand creating a regular expression for .net that matches a comma separated list of years

Examples:

```
1990
1985,1990,2004
```

Year range between 1900 and 2100

Comment: Checking range of values in regular expression is major pain... Are you sure you have to use regex?

Comment: What do you want to do with the commas? Do you need only the years which are seperated by commas? Do you want to replace them? Be more specific.

Comment: Why not split and test each value?

Comment: Why not just Split() http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: Side note: feels somewhat too broad without any code you've tried/sample usage.

Comment: I just need to make sure that the string is a list of comma separated years

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) :) You really should be clear in what you *need* and what you think solution should be. At this point it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as possibly there is no real need for regex.

Answer (score 3):

> Year range between 1900 and 2100

```
^(?:19\d\d|2(?:100|0\d\d))(?:,(?:19\d\d|2(?:100|0\d\d)))*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fW8xM9/2)

Comment: *Year range between 1900 and 2100*, you might want to update the first `199\d` to `19\d\d`

Comment: yep, i forget that. Thanks, updated now.